# EAGLContexts sharing EAGLSharegroup giving error when subclassing GLKView

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ffmpeg, opengl-es-2.0

i am trying to create a player using FFMPEG which can display frame using OpenGl. The `player` class has three threads: one for rendering (Runs a runloop and handles a render event triggered every N ms.) - it fetches `GLKTextureInfo` stored in pictureQueue and renders.
 one for reading packets from VideoStream and putting them in a videoQueue, the third one fetches the packets from the videoQueue and decodes them and creates a `GLKTextureInfo` and stores it in pictureQueue.

**Case 1:**
The `player` class subclasses `GLKView` and creates a `EAGLContext` sets it as its context and also as currentContext in rendering thread (it's the first thread that starts).

```
EAGLContext *mycontext = [self createBestEaglContext];
if (!self.mycontext || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:mycontext]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create Base EAGLContext");
    return;
}
[self setContext:mycontext];
```

and then starts the `stream decoding thread` which in turn starts the `Video Packet Decoding Thread` if it finds a video stream.then

```
// set's the params for the GLKBaseEffect
// set's up VBO's
// run's runloop
```

The `Video Packet Decoding Thread` also creates `EAGLContext` which shares the earlier created contexts `EAGLSharegroup`.

```
self.videoPacketDecodeThreadContext = [self createEaglContextForOtherThread];
if (!self.videoPacketDecodeThreadContext || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.videoPacketDecodeThreadContext])
{
    NSLog(@"Could not create video packet decode thread context");
}
```

texture part

```
UIImage* image = [self ImageFromAVPicture:*(AVPicture*)pFrameRGB width:self.is.video_stream->codec->width height:self.is.video_stream->codec->height];

NSError *error = nil;
GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                                                               options:nil
                                                                 error:&error];
if (error)
{
   NSLog(@"Texture loading Error: %@\n", error.description);
   //return -1;
}
else
{
   [self.is.pictQueue_lock lock];
   [self.is.pictQueue enqueue:textureInfo];
   [self.is.pictQueue_lock unlock];
}
```

i get a **error** saying: `Failed to bind EAGLDrawable: <CAEAGLLayer: 0x156f7e50> to GL_RENDERBUFFER 1` and `Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6` and `glerror 1280`.

**Case 2:** The `Player` doesn't subclass `GLKView` instead it is set as a delegate to the `GLKView` created in storyboard.

```
-(void)initPlayerWithView:(GLKView*)v
{
   self.view = v;
}
```

and set everyThing as above (sets `self.view` context to `mycontext`) everything runs fine.

`-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` And `-(void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` are both called on `Rendering Thread`. Rendering code:

```
    {
      [self.is.pictQueue_lock lock];
      GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo = (GLKTextureInfo*)[self.is.pictQueue dequeue];
      [self.is.pictQueue_lock unlock];

      // delete the previous texture
      GLuint index = self.baseEffect.texture2d0.name;
      glDeleteTextures(1, &index);

      self.baseEffect.texture2d0.name = textureInfo.name;
      self.baseEffect.texture2d0.target = textureInfo.target;

      [self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

      // Enable vertex buffer
      glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

      //Enable texture buffer
      glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, textureCoords));
      glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    }
```

How do i resolve the error in Case 1 ?. Also if their are other things i can do in a different way please suggest like:

1. Am i using to many threads ?
2. I am converting the decoded frame to a UIImage and then creating a texture from it. can it be done differently ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't about GLKView, I've written a player using NSOpenGLView in OSX, and subclassing works fine there, but I let it create the context for me.

> Am i using to many threads ?

By default, for most codecs, ffmpeg uses [frame multithreading](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/multithreading.txt), which means the main decoding thread does nothing, it creates subthreads and waits for them to finish decoding frames. (For realtime communication, you can also use slice multithreading, which decreases latency, but scales less well, and requires bitstream support.) If you're not doing anything specific to tell it otherwise, ffmpeg uses frame multithreading, and your frame decoding thread does nothing. So you don't need it. The player thread can decode video directly.

> I am converting the decoded frame to a
>   UIImage and then creating a texture from it. can it be done
>   differently ?

UIImage is in RGB, and most video decoders output YUV, so this suggests some other code is doing software YUV-RGB conversion. This RGB conversion will be slow, very slow.

Instead, consider that openGL can draw YUV directly. So I would not use UIImage, but instead draw the YUV planes directly using a shader to do the YUV-RGB conversion inside the hardware.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i am using `swscale` for YUV-RGB conversion. I haven't created a shader instead i am using `GLKBaseEffect`, can it accept YUV planes ?

Comment: No, you need a shader for YUV-RGB conversion. If you search, you'll find numerous examples of how that works.